# Retrofit :Unable to create adapter

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using retrofit for HTTP calls. But app throws following exception :

> 02-21 14:07:40.527 21157-21157/com.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.popularmovies, PID: 21157
>                                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for
>   class com.entity.PopularMovies
>                                                                                          for method MovieDbAPI.getPopularMovies
>                                                                                          at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:177)
>                                                                                          at retrofit.MethodHandler.createCallAdapter(MethodHandler.java:47)
>                                                                                          at retrofit.MethodHandler.create(MethodHandler.java:26)
>                                                                                          at retrofit.Retrofit.loadMethodHandler(Retrofit.java:151)
>                                                                                          at retrofit.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:132)
>                                                                                          at $Proxy1.getPopularMovies(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.service.MovieServiceImpl.getPopularMovies(MovieServiceImpl.java:27)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.popularmovies.MainActivityFragment.getPopularMovies(MainActivityFragment.java:49)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.popularmovies.MainActivityFragment.onClick(MainActivityFragment.java:77)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call
>   adapter for class com.entity.PopularMovies. Tried:
>                                                                                       * retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
>                                                                                          at retrofit.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:207)
>                                                                                          at retrofit.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:175)
>                                                                                          at retrofit.MethodHandler.createCallAdapter(MethodHandler.java:45)
>                                                                                             ... 18 more

```
public class MovieServiceImpl implements MovieService{

private static String baseURL =  "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie/";

private static String sortBy = "popularity.desc";
private static String key ="*****";

@Override
public PopularMovies  getPopularMovies(){

  Retrofit retrofit = Util.getRetrofit(baseURL);

  MovieDbAPI movieAPI = retrofit.create(MovieDbAPI.class);

  PopularMovies popularMovies =  movieAPI.getPopularMovies( sortBy, key );

  return popularMovies;
}
}

public class Util {


public static Retrofit getRetrofit(String baseURL){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}


}



 public interface MovieDbAPI {

 @GET
 PopularMovies getPopularMovies(@Query("sort_by") String sort_by,   @Query("api_key") String key);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@GET
Call<PopularMovies> getPopularMovies(@Query("sort_by") String sort_by, @Query("api_key") String key);
```

and when you call `getPopularMovies` method make it this way:

**Synchronous Request**

```
Call<PopularMovies> call = movieAPI.getPopularMovies(sortBy, key);
PopularMovies popularMovies = call.execute();
```

or **Asynchronous Request**

```
Call<PopularMovies> call = movieAPI.getPopularMovies(sortBy, key);
call.enqueue(new Callback<PopularMovies>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<PopularMovies> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```